# Magento 2: how to show a message when customer order get free shipping?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I want to display a message in minicart and / or in other sections of my store when customer order is equals or more than X amount.

I know that when Free shipping option is enabled, this is shown in the cart. However, I would like to display the "Free shipping!" message in other blocks or sections of the store.

This is useful when the option to redirect to cart after clicking the "Add to cart" button is disabled. In this case, since customers stay on the product page, they don't see immediately they got free shipping.

Comment: have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. I would like to a customer to know they have hit a certain promotion as they purchase x amount of products or break x amount of dollars.